# How to trigger a new line in jade/pug?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I want to write several object attributes in a singular table tab each on a **new line**

here's my pug table code excerpt

```
table#posts(style="float:right; border: 1px solid green")
        tbody  
            each post in data
                 tr
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green")='Name: ' + post.firstname + ' ' + post.lastname  + 'Date of Birth: ' + post.dob
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green") buttons                    
            else
                 tr  
                    td No posts!
```

I want the new line to be between the Name and date of birth. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `<br />` tag

```
table#posts(style="float:right; border: 1px solid green")
        tbody  
            each post in data
                 tr
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green")
                      | Name: #{post.firstname + ' ' + post.lastname}
                      br
                      | Date of Birth: #{post.dob}
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green") buttons                    
            else
                 tr  
                    td No posts!
```

You can also enclose name and date of birth text within a `<p>` tag

Comment: I tried this method, it outputs "'Name: ' + post.firstname + ' ' + post.lastname" as a string and doesn't access the post data.

Answer (score 2):

Put the text on a new line with a preceding `|`:

```
table#posts(style="float:right; border: 1px solid green")
        tbody  
            each post in data
                 tr
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green")
                      | 'Name: ' + post.firstname + ' ' + post.lastname
                      br
                      | 'Date of Birth: ' + post.dob
                    td(style="border: 1px solid green") buttons                    
            else
                 tr  
                    td No posts!
```